# Same time complexty but highly varying runtimes

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes

For the question: Given an even number ( greater than 2 ), return two prime numbers whose sum will be equal to given number.

The following algorithms have time complexity O(A<sup>2.5</sup>) and O(Alog(log(A)) respectively. Still for values of A (an integer) as large as 73939138 the second one is really slow. I've tried for many inputs and the first one is faster. Can you please explain why?

```
int ul=A/2;
vector <int> answer;
for (int i=1; i<=ul; i++)
{
    if (check(i)==1 && check(A-i)==1 ) //check(i) checks primality of i in O(i^1.5)
   {
       int myint[2] ={ i,A-i };
       answer.assign( myint, myint+2);
       return answer;
   }
}
```

---

```
vector<bool> primes(A+1,true);
int i,j;
//Sieve of Eratosthenes O(Alog(log(A)))
for(i=2;i*i<A+1;i++)
{
    if(primes[i])
    {
        for(j=2;i*j<A+1;j++)
            primes[i*j]=0;
    }
}
vector<int> arr,answer;
//arr is vector containing all primes from 2 to A; O(A)
for(i=2;i<A+1;i++)
{
    if(primes[i])
        arr.push_back(i);
}
i=0;j=arr.size()-1;
//Algorithm to find 2 numbers summing up to a value
while(i<=j)
{
    if(arr[i]+arr[j]>A)
        j--;
    else if(arr[i]+arr[j]<A)
        i++;
    else
    {
        answer.push_back(arr[i]);
        answer.push_back(arr[j]);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Edit: check(n) is defined as follows:

```
int check(int n)
{
    int ul=sqrt(n);
    if(n<2)
        return 0;
    for(int i=2; i<=ul; i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complexities you consider do not give you immediate information on the performance of the algorithms, but information regarding the **asymptotic** behavior, usually for **worst-case** scenario.

---

#### Worst case vs. Average-case

Just look at the answer for `A = 73939138`:

```
73939138 = 5 + 73939133
```

So basically, your first algorithm does ~10 calls to `check` while the second is going through huge loop to fill the array `primes`..

The **average-case** complexity of the first algorithm is probably much lower than `O(A^2.5)`, while the average-case complexity of the second algorithm is close or equal to `O(A log(log(A))`.

**Note:** What follows about the average-case complexities are merely guesses, don't take them for sound results.

**Second algorithm:**

In this algorithm, whatever `A` is, you have to fill the array `primes` using the *sieve of Eratosthenes*, which is `O(A log(log(A)))`. Since this is the most time-consuming part of the algorithm, the average-case complexity of this algorithm is likely close to its worst-case complexity, so `O(A log(log(A)))`.

**First algorithm:**

It is more complicated here... Basically, it depends on the results of the algorithm. According to [Wikipedia's page on Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture), the average number of ways of writing `A` as the sum of two primes is `A / (2 * log(A) ^ 2)`.

Since a prime cannot contribute to two different ways, it means that there are in average `2 * A / (2 * log(A) ^ 2) = A / (log(A) ^ 2)` primes that contribute to one of the ways.

If we **assume*<sup>1</sup> these primes are uniformly distributed, the smaller one should be close to `A / (A / log(A) ^ 2) = log(A)^2`.

So you would only have to check numbers up to approximately `log(A)^2`.

<sub><sup>1</sup> I have **strictly no idea** if this is true, I am just making a guess...</sub>

---

#### Asymptotic behavior

Check [@PeterBecker's answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48096726/2666289).

When you said `O(A log(log(A)))` complexity, you are hiding a lot of things — Any function `f(A) = C * (A log(log(A))) + g(A)` where `g(A)` is `O(A log(log(A)))` is also `O(A log(log(A)))`.

For instance:

```
f(A) = c1 * A * log(log(A)) + c2 * A + c3 * log(A)
```

...is `O(A log(log(A)))`.

The coefficients `c1`, `c2`, `c3` are what dictates the real behavior of your algorithm implementation, and unfortunately these are often hard to find (or complex).

For instance, one quick look at your implementation shows the following:

- The first algorithm does not use any kind of containers, and thus have few memory requirements (only some local variables).
- The second algorithm uses two relatively huge arrays, `primes` and `arr` — If `A = 73939138`:

  - `primes` contains `73939139` "entity" — This is likely optimized by the specialization of `std::vector<bool>`, but you would still need ~9MB, which does not fit in a L1 cache,  maybe a L2, and you need some bit-wise operations for each access.
  - `arr` should contain ~4000000 `int` (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)), and you need multiple allocations since you are using `push_back`.

Comment: I understand that worst-case complexity need not always occur. But how do I judge by looking at the algorithm whose average time complexity would be better. ?

Comment: @Tanay This is explained in my answer, whatever `n` is, the second algorithms still needs to compute all the primes up to `n`, which is the most-consuming part of the algorithm, so its average complexity is close (if not equal) to its worst-case. For the first algorithm, it is more complicated, I'll try to add some information to my answer.

Comment: @Tanay I have edited the answer. Please note that I am making **HUGE** assumption here, but you should get the idea behind it.

Comment: Now, this is a solution I was looking for @Holt. Thank you so much!!

Comment: +1, this is a good answer. I believe the first algorithm does a somewhat better than your analysis because instead of using two "random" primes it starts with p=3, then next tries 5, 7, 11, etc. These first integers are much more likely to be prime than 1/log(A). I believe it, but I can't prove it either ;). My guess is the complexity is O(log(A) * log(log(A)) steps.

Answer (score 8):

Time complexity is **not** about how **fast** an algorithm runs, but about how it's speed **scales** as the problem becomes larger. An algorithm that spends 1 second on each element has the same time complexity as an algorithm that spends 1 microsecond on each element: O(n). In both cases, if you have 10 times as many elements, the algorithm will take 10 times as long to run.

Comment: So if I were to face such a problem of selecting an algorithm, then how would I judge which one is better suited for my purpose? Will I have to run and check it for all possible inputs and see which one is better?

Comment: @Tanay You check it for the relevant inputs and see which one is better. You possible also find the point from which one algorithm is better than the other and decide based on input size which algorithm to use.

Comment: @Tanay -- choosing an algorithm requires understanding the algorithm and its data sensitivities. Time complexity doesn't give you an answer; it helps you understand what's going on. An O(n^2) algorithm might be a better choice than an O(n) algorithm if the latter does a great deal of wheel spinning and the data is small enough.